How to show mean in time series graph reactively?
I want to achieve this sort of plot dynamically using shiny. It is to show the year on year set of data with the yearly average of within the year. I am able to get it outside of shiny, but I'd like to have an app so I can review different pairings of variables to see what's going on.
emphasized text

When I try this in shiny, I get the plot without the moving average.
It looks like this:

My code is below:
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput('ycol1', 'Select first Y Variable', names(db)),
      selectInput('size1', 'Select first size variable', names(db)),
      selectInput('ycol2', 'Select second Y Variable', names(d)),
      selectInput('size2', 'Select second size Variable', names(d)),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output,session) {
  y <- reactive({ db[, input$ycol1] })
  y2 <- reactive({ d[, input$ycol2] })
  size <- reactive({ db[, input$size1] })
  size2 <- reactive({ d[, input$size2] })

  group1 <- reactive({
    db %>% group_by(years) %>%
      summarise(mean = mean(input$ycol1))
  })
  
  group2 <- reactive({
    d %>% group_by(years) %>%
      summarise(mean = mean(input$ycol2))
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot() + 
      geom_point(aes(x=db$years, y = y(), size = size()), col='red', alpha=0.3) + 
      geom_point(aes(y=y2(), x=d$years, size = size2()), col = 'darkgreen', alpha=0.3) +
      geom_line(aes(x=group1()$years, y = group1()$mean), col='red') +
      geom_line(aes(x=group1()$years, y = group1()$mean), col='darkgreen') 
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)

What am I missing?
data as csv for reference:
municipalities,years,PI,ave.alt,ave.slope,percent.water,TempMaxSumYear,TempMinSumYear,TempMaxWinYear,TempMinWinYear
água santa,2002,0,774.572815534,12.4101,17.6974026941,27.54875,16.795,17.8705,7.6047875
água santa,2003,0.0926640927,774.572815534,12.4101,17.6974026941,28.455,16.954375,20.506875,8.7186375
água santa,2004,0.0489130435,774.572815534,12.4101,17.6974026941,28.19375,16.979375,23.6803125,12.526625
água santa,2005,0.1236263736,774.572815534,12.4101,17.6974026941,28.684375,16.6275,17.1528125,9.0095625
água santa,2006,0.0859872611,774.572815534,12.4101,17.6974026941,27.026875,18.47875,19.859375,9.00713125
água santa,2007,0.0666666667,774.572815534,12.4101,17.6974026941,27.92875,17.823125,24.66375,13.015625
água santa,2008,0,774.572815534,12.4101,17.6974026941,25.36875,15.869375,18.3678125,8.41500625
água santa,2009,0,774.572815534,12.4101,17.6974026941,27.228125,16.215625,20.14,12.2789375
água santa,2010,0.0503144654,774.572815534,12.4101,17.6974026941,27.3875,17.72,21.178125,12.288125
agudo,2002,0.0947368421,407.712389381,24.5182,15.9689860196,30.561875,19.44625,19.090625,9.2718125
agudo,2003,0,407.712389381,24.5182,15.9689860196,31.141875,19.37375,20.894375,9.237
agudo,2004,0,407.712389381,24.5182,15.9689860196,30.441875,19.1575,23.96125,13.56625
agudo,2005,0.0333333333,407.712389381,24.5182,15.9689860196,30.324375,16.899375,16.7575,8.363125
agudo,2006,0.2162162162,407.712389381,24.5182,15.9689860196,28.274375,19.110625,19.2931875,8.6406875
agudo,2007,0,407.712389381,24.5182,15.9689860196,28.64125,19.149375,26.29375,15.708125
agudo,2008,0,407.712389381,24.5182,15.9689860196,26.83,17.038125,18.3729375,9.29475
agudo,2009,0,407.712389381,24.5182,15.9689860196,29.051875,18.15,21.09375,13.132625
agudo,2010,0.3888888889,407.712389381,24.5182,15.9689860196,29.844375,19.703125,20.36875,12.4310625
alegria,2003,0,381.962962963,15.002,18.2600987717,32.520625,19.91125,24.050625,10.2309375
alegria,2004,0,381.962962963,15.002,18.2600987717,32.4425,20.22625,26.29125,15.0344375
alegria,2005,0,381.962962963,15.002,18.2600987717,31.98375,18.731875,19.6,10.382625
alegria,2006,0,381.962962963,15.002,18.2600987717,31.325,20.259375,21.95875,9.7706875
alegria,2007,0,381.962962963,15.002,18.2600987717,30.994375,20.284375,29.060625,14.6423125
alegria,2008,0,381.962962963,15.002,18.2600987717,29.72375,18.8275,21.89075,10.3185625
alegria,2009,0,381.962962963,15.002,18.2600987717,31.02375,18.784375,23.510625,13.7511875
alegria,2010,0,381.962962963,15.002,18.2600987717,31.8,20.263125,24.079375,19.283125


Your inputs are characters which contain the name of a column, i.e. your are trying to compute the mean of a character and you should get a warning about that in the console. Instead try with the .data pro-noun, e.g. mean(.data[[input$ycol1]]). Also note that passing vectors to aesthetics is bad practice and not recommended. Instead you can do e.g. geom_line(data = group1, aes(x=years, y = mean))

Thank you Stefan! This cracked it. Works now!
